# pyspark two dataframes subtractbykey issue

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, comparison, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to output a dataframe only with columns identified with different values after comparing two dataframes. I am finding difficulty in identifying an approach to proceed.

```
    **Code:**
df_a = sql_context.createDataFrame([("a", 3,"apple","bear","carrot"), ("b", 5,"orange","lion","cabbage"), ("c", 7,"pears","tiger","onion"),("c", 8,"jackfruit","elephant","raddish"),("c", 8,"watermelon","giraffe","tomato")], ["name", "id","fruit","animal","veggie"])
df_b = sql_context.createDataFrame([("a", 3,"apple","bear","carrot"), ("b", 5,"orange","lion","cabbage"), ("c", 7,"banana","tiger","onion"),("c", 8,"jackfruit","camel","raddish")], ["name", "id","fruit","animal","veggie"])
df_a = df_a.alias('df_a')
df_b = df_b.alias('df_b')
df = df_a.join(df_b, (df_a.id == df_b.id) & (df_a.name == df_b.name),'leftanti').select('df_a.*').show()
```

Trying to match based on the ids (id,name) between dataframe1 & dataframe2

```
Dataframe 1:
+----+---+----------+--------+-------+
|name| id|     fruit|  animal| veggie|
+----+---+----------+--------+-------+
|   a|  3|     apple|    bear| carrot|
|   b|  5|    orange|    lion|cabbage|
|   c|  7|     pears|   tiger|  onion|
|   c|  8| jackfruit|elephant|raddish|
|   c|  9|watermelon| giraffe| tomato|
+----+---+----------+--------+-------+

Dataframe 2:
+----+---+---------+------+-------+
|name| id|    fruit|animal| veggie|
+----+---+---------+------+-------+
|   a|  3|    apple|  bear| carrot|
|   b|  5|   orange|  lion|cabbage|
|   c|  7|   banana| tiger|  onion|
|   c|  8|jackfruit| camel|raddish|
+----+---+---------+------+-------+



Expected dataframe
+----+---+----------+--------+
|name| id|     fruit|  animal|
+----+---+----------+--------+
|   c|  7|     pears|   tiger|
|   c|  8| jackfruit|elephant|
|   c|  9|watermelon| giraffe|
+----+---+----------+--------+
```

Comment: why you do not have the last column `veggie` ?

Comment: veggie column is not available because there are no mismatches between two dataframes for the veggie column based on the key provided.

Comment: tomatoes is not a mismatch?

Comment: Trying to match based on the ids (id,name) between dataframe1 & dataframe2. The record which contain tomato is missing same ids in dataframe2, so this record is not considered for comparison. Sorry for not providing more clarity in my original post. I have  updated my original post now.

Comment: I still do not understand ... line`c 9` doesn't exist in df_2, therefore every column should be brought back or none ... why you only bring back the 2 first columns ? I think you are trying to sum up a functionnal problem with fruits and animal, and it doesnt make sense at all ...

Comment: I will explain my approach, please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166318/discussion-between-steven-and-jack).